# What region of the complex plane does $\left|{z-1+i}\right|+\left|{z+1-i}\right|=6$ fill?

Tags: complex-numbers

What region of the complex plane does $\left|{z-1+i}\right|+\left|{z+1-i}\right|=6$ fill?

I'm having a tough time figuring what region this fills up. Maybe its easy, but for some reason I cant think it through and was hoping someone could give a hint or two.

The only important thing I've noticed is that $(-1+i)$ and $(1-i)$ point in opposite directions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**

What conic section is such that there are two points $F$ and $F'$ in its interior, such that for any point $M$ on its boundary, there's a certain sum of distances that is always constant?

Comment: So its an ellipse with foci (-1+i); (1-i)? :D makes sense